# Draw.io images export

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I've been trying to export a few boxes with text to an image for the past few minutes but the text keeps getting truncated if it's space separated. It's pretty weird. I've tried with another draw.io instance in a separate window but it's still the same.

To replicate, just select any box (any shape really), place some space-separated text in it like `hello world` and then try to export it to PNG or JPG. In the image, the `world` part just disappears. Only PDFs still work as expected. Since I used this app last week without this problem, I'd like to know if this is somehow related to my draw.io settings or a general bug.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to repeat all the steps in a different browser or/and Incognito mode. Also, clear the cache and temporarily disable all browser extensions.
Incognito mode is great for testing cause it is cache and extension free (cache and extensions can cause some problems sometimes)

Also, you can try both:
File > Export as > PNG
File > Export as > Advanced > PNG

I hope something will help.